# get index of child with event.currentTarget

Tags: javascript, dhtml

How to get rid of jQuery's ".index()" here? All I am looking for is a native way to get the index of the button clicked, see source code below (works perfectly but I really couldn't find any Vanilla-JS solution for this and I don't want to use jQuery for such a small task). Thanks.

```js
    function navButtonClick(ev) {
        var buttonIndex = $(ev.currentTarget).index(); /* How to get rid of jQuery? */

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = buttonIndex;
    }

    function startTemplate() {
        var i;
        var navItems = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation button");

        for (i=0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
            navItems[i].addEventListener("click", navButtonClick);
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startTemplate);
```

```html
The HTML part looks like this:

    <nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
        <button type="button"> <em>Navi tab 1</em> </button>
        <button type="button"> Navi tab 2 </button>
        <button type="button"> Navi tab 3 </button>
        <button type="button"> Navi tab 4 </button>
    </nav>

    <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two different ways. First, pass the index of the buttons to the corresponding function while adding the event listeners:

```
function navButtonClick(buttonIndex) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = buttonIndex;
}

function startTemplate() {
    var i;
    var navItems = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation button");
    for (i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
        navItems[i].addEventListener("click", navButtonClick.bind(null, i));
    }
}

startTemplate();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67L2g13z/1/)

Second, create a function which will dynamically check the index of the element:

```
function navButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = getIndex(this);
}

function getIndex(elm) {
  var parent = elm.parentElement;
  for (var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
    if (parent.children[i].isEqualNode(elm)) {
        return i;
    }
  }
}

function startTemplate() {
    var i;
    var navItems = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation button");
    for (i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
        navItems[i].addEventListener("click", navButtonClick);
    }
}

startTemplate();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67L2g13z/2/)

Comment: Perfect, both possibilities work for me. Since I also like using strict mode ("use strict") I just changed "getIndex(this);" to "getIndex(ev.currentTarget);" and I've added "ev" as a parameter in "function navButtonClick(ev)".

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
function navButtonClick(ev) {
    var buttonIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentElement.children, this);

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = buttonIndex;
}

function startTemplate() {
    var i;
    var navItems = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation button");

    for (i=0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
        navItems[i].addEventListener("click", navButtonClick);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startTemplate);
```

Check the snippet below:

```js
function navButtonClick(ev) {
  var buttonIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentElement.children, this);

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = buttonIndex;
}

function startTemplate() {
  var i;
  var navItems = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation button");

  for (i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    navItems[i].addEventListener("click", navButtonClick);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startTemplate);
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
  <button type="button"> <em>Navi tab 1</em> 
  </button>
  <button type="button">Navi tab 2</button>
  <button type="button">Navi tab 3</button>
  <button type="button">Navi tab 4</button>
</nav>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Useful, thanks! In strict mode it's possible to change it into `var buttonIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(ev.currentTarget.parentElement.children, ev.currentTarget);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function navButtonClick(index) {
    return function (ev) {
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = index;
    }
}

function startTemplate() {
    var i;
    var navItems = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation button");

    for (i=0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
        navItems[i].addEventListener("click", navButtonClick(i));
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startTemplate);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, it works :)

Anyway, only for buttons (I need `closest` in chrome even for them).

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var target = event.target, nodes, i;
  
  if (target.closest) {
    target = target.closest('button');
  }
                                                     
  if (target && target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    nodes = target.parentElement.children; 
    for (i=0; nodes[i]!==target; ++i);
    document.querySelector("output").textContent = i;
  }
})
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
  <button type="button"> <em>Navi tab 1</em> </button>
  <button type="button"> Navi tab 2 </button>
  <button type="button"> Navi tab 3 </button>
  <button type="button"> Navi tab 4 </button>
</nav>

<output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6-style answer:

```
const indexOf = element => Array.from(element.parentNode.children).indexOf(element)

const buttonIndex = indexOf(event.currentTarget)
```